# Do I need to enable Dev Hub in my PROD Org?

Tags: salesforcedx, dev-hub

I want to adopt Salesforce DX development. Do I have to enable Dev Hub in my Prod Org, or can I activate it in a new Developer Edition, do my development in scratch orgs and eventually deploy the packages to my DEV, QA, UAT and PROD orgs?

Background: I am a developer and currently we develop in our personal dev sandboxes and push our code through other sandboxes (DEV, QA, UAT) and then to Prod org. My company does not want to give developers Prod access at all, even limited access licenses, so I don't think we should enable Dev Hub in Prod.

So I need to know if having a Dev Hub org that is not my Prod org is ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dev Hub can be enabled in Developer Edition orgs, but the scratch org limits are significantly lower than in paid Salesforce production orgs. In a Developer Edition org, the limits are just [3 active and 6 daily scratch orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs.htm), which *might* suffice for an individual developer who is not using continuous integration but can be stifling in a process that likes to use a lot of orgs. It's not feasible to share a Developer Edition Dev Hub across a team; each developer would need their own.

Production orgs, as described in the linked documentation, offer an order of magnitude more scratch orgs. To use Dev Hub in production, you can request special [free, limited access licenses](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/dev_hub_license.htm) (I wasn't sure if that's what you were alluding to in your question) to enable developers to authenticate and create scratch orgs against Prod, without viewing CRM data.

Of course, some organizations may be unwilling for compliance or process reasons even to use those licenses, in which case you don't have much recourse other than a separate paid org or multiple Developer Editions.

Comment: Thank you, I was indeed referring to that limited access licenses. I think the limitations you mention are sufficient reason to try to change their mind on allowing us access to Prod. TPTB implied there was leeway in that regard.

Answer (score 5):

> So I need to know if having a Dev Hub org that is not my Prod org is ok.

Typically it should be OK. However you will end up having limited number of Scratch Orgs that you can create using a DE Org.

The [Enable Dev Hub in Your Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_enable_devhub.htm) documentation lists down all such considerations while using a trial or DE Org as Dev Hub. One of the key considerations out there is as below, so you should plan your implementation approach depending on the scenario.

> If you plan to create package versions or run continuous integration jobs, it’s better to use a production or business org as your Dev Hub because of higher scratch org and package version limits. Package versions are associated with your Dev Hub org. When a trial or Developer Edition org expires, you lose access to the package versions.

Comment: Thank you, I think if I explain it this way I might be able to convince TPTB to allow us to have limited access licenses and enable the Dev Hub in Prod.